# node.js tmi.js twitch bot Object Returning [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, twitch

I'm making a game for a twitch bot using node.js and tmi.js. I have an array which is dynamic(votePlayers), that changes each round depending on incoming messages on the twitch chat that are read by the bot. I then must have a counter for each time an item appears in this array, so I used the below approach to do so, which worked, and when I console log the object the data is saved to, all appears fine, but when I try to return it as a message from the bot to the twitch chat, it returns [object, Object], despite being printed correctly to the console. I have no idea what's going wrong and what I can do.

```js
//calculate function 
function calculateWinner () {
    let roundCount = {};
    votePlayers.forEach(function(i) { roundCount[i] = (roundCount[i]||0) + 1;});
    console.log(roundCount);
    client.say(channel, `The votes for this round are: ${roundCount}`);
    newRound();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.say` expects a string as second argument, yet you're passing an object, that's why you're getting `[object Object]`.

First convert your object to string:
i.e.

```
roundCount = {};
roundCount[1] = 5;
roundCount["2"] = 3;

console.log(Object.keys(roundCount).map(key => `${key}: ${roundCount[key]}`).join(", "));
```

then calling

```
client.say(channel, `The votes for this round are: ${Object.keys(roundCount).map(key => `${key}: ${roundCount[key]}`).join(", ")}`);
```

should work

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Appreciate the help.